# c++ Variadic boost fusion map alias template

Tags: c++, tuples, variadic-templates, boost-fusion

Consider this snippet:

```
#include <boost/fusion/container/map.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/pair.hpp>

struct MsgA {};
struct MsgB {};

using MsgList = std::tuple<MsgA, MsgB>;

template <typename Msg>
class MsgSignal {};

template <typename... Args>
using MsgSignals =
    boost::fusion::map<boost::fusion::pair<Args, MsgSignal<Args>>, ...>;

int main() {
    MsgSignals<MsgList> signals;
    // signals should be of type boost::fusion::map<boost::fusion::pair<MsgA, MsgSignal<MsgA>,
                                                    boost::fusion::pair<MsgB, MsgSignal<MsgB>>>                                     >
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/nMbnYWhMs)

I'm struggling with the alias template `MsgSignals`.

What is the right syntax such that the type of `signals` becomes

```
boost::fusion::map<boost::fusion::pair<MsgA, MsgSignal<MsgA>,
                   boost::fusion::pair<MsgB, MsgSignal<MsgB>>>
```

Comment: Typo BTW: `pair</*..*/>, ...` -> `pair</*..*/>...` (comma removed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use template partial specialization to extract the types in `std::tuple`:

```
template <typename Tuple>
struct MsgSignalsImpl;

template <typename... Args>
struct MsgSignalsImpl<std::tuple<Args...>> {
  using type = boost::fusion::map<boost::fusion::pair<Args, MsgSignal<Args>>...>;
};

template <typename Tuple>
using MsgSignals = typename MsgSignalsImpl<Tuple>::type;
```

[Demo.](https://godbolt.org/z/xEz9aPW9T)